# Removing bathtub tread

Tags: bathtub

I work for a well known hotel chain. Corporate has mandated that we replace the bathtub tread with a corporate approved product. In order to do so I must remove the current tread from 94 rooms.

I have tried everything available to me. Paint and varnish stripper, goof off, brute force.

I have a sharpened spackle tool that I'm using to try and scrape it off. I don't have to worry about damaging the enamel coat on the (steel I believe) bathtubs. I have spray that can cover any scratches.

I am trying to remove a 2 step non slip kit that is: Bathworks brand - bathtub bottom non-slip kit.

A link to the product is here:

https://www.bath-works.net/product/PREMIUM-BATHTUB-REFINISHING-KIT-WITH-NON-SLIP-PROTECTION

I still have a couple ideas, but I'm getting frustrated. I still need to try a heat gun and gasoline. If I have no success I also intend call the product manufacturer and ask them directly. If I have success I will answer the question myself but i could really use some advice from someone who had experience with something similar.

Any suggestions?

Edit: not sure if this would be exactly the right place for this question. SE has so many sites. Please let me know if there is a more appropriate place so I can move this question there

Comment: Definitely call the manuf and ask them; they might have a recommended solvent. There are many chemicals that are marketed as paint/varnish stripper and some may be more effective on this. But you're not just trying to peel off a sticker, you're trying to remove a cured finish. If you're really out of luck, you may need to grind it off and re-enamel the tub. :/

Comment: @ShimonRura I just got off the phone with them and they say to sand it off. I really would prefer not to do that unless there's no other choice since that means I'm guaranteed to have refinish all of them. I'm going to try a couple ideas. If you can recommend any solvents that might do better than 91 octane gasoline, it would be appreciated =)

Comment: I'm not a chemist, and don't want to speculate on this. Whatever you try, make sure you have a proper chemical respirator and great ventilation. Randomly mixing chemicals is a great way to get yourself killed!

Comment: At this point I'd recommend considering having the tubs replaced, professionally resurfaced, or professionally lined. Or go up the chain to corporate. Or see if your guests suddenly decide to start dropping sledgehammers during showers, necessitating replacement of 94 tubs.

Comment: Gasoline would be a very, very dangerous option (and probably violate a number of local codes, as well as invalidate insurance coverage if you happen to start a fire while trying it) and probably ineffective as well. If the tubs are plastic, a heat gun is dubious - if cast iron, it might help. But if the manufacturer says sand it off" that's probably what you'll have to do.

Comment: @ShimonRura LMFAO... That made my day man. Thank you for that. I like you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would definitely use a respirator. And I agree with you about the risks. Gas didn't work. Heat didn't work. Those tread kits are definitely worth the money. I'm just gonna buy a belt sander. When it works I'll post the answer unless someone beats me to it. Free upvote if anyone wants it

Comment: "...I still need to try a heat gun and gasoline..." not simultaneously, I hope...

Comment: @IconDaemon lol... If I did I'm sure corporate would finally just approve the remodel I've been begging for like two years now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manufacturer recommends sand paper. Solvents are ineffective. Perhaps in a sealed enviroment solvents might work, but everything evaporates too quickly. I have gotten the stuff off and here is how.

Sand with 36 grit paper on a belt sander.

Patches may remain if the tub does not have a flat bottom. If so, use large grit paper by hand to sand off patches.

36 grit paper WILL leave the surface dull, and over sanding can cause series damage. A razor proves effective when submerged in goof off. But only for small patches. You will need to refinish the surface no matter what. ESPECIALLY if you use a razor.

If your unlucky enough to need to do this, I am truly sorry. There is no easy way. Give up hope.

Comment: Konner, please accept your answer so the question can be resolved.